# Android: ListView Background color not applying to the whole listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom ListView and I am trying to apply a background color on it but it only applies on the area where there is no list Item. I have tried many techniques but it won't working for me. I want to make the background color on the whole listview please help me how to achieve it.
Here is my XML code

```
<ListView 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/user"
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sub_title">

            </ListView>
```

This is its result

[image]

And this is what i want

[image]

Comment: it is getting applied but is covered by the List items. To achieve above you will have to set the same background to your ListView items as well. :)

Comment: you need to use the same background color on your list items. or apply list itself with transparent background

Comment: I have tried the same background color on list items too but it doesn't working and also I have applied the transparent color for listview and a background color for its parent view.

Comment: Could you post the layout file of your list items, and your custom Array Adapter if you are using one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a transparent background color for your ListView items' layout, or use the same background color on your list items.

For the transparent background solution, you can apply this in your item's xml file

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Could you post the layout file of your list items?

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/brown"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/programsLV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>



</RelativeLayout>
```